# Inflater XML Resource Type

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inflater, android-inflate, bottomnavigationview

I'am testing a new library called BottomBar of roughike, and this library help you to create a BottomBar like BottomNavigationView and this libries define your tabs in an XML resource file.

Example:

res/xml/bottombar_tabs.xml:

how can I inflate this menu? I already tried a lot of things. Obs: I can't move this file to another place.

In an old version of this library, I did this:
res/menu/bottombar_tabs

```
public boolean onCreateOptionaMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return true;
}
```

I already tried this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionalMenu(Xml xml){
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.xml.bottombar_tabs, xml);

    return true;
}
```

but getLayout and getMenu can't do that, and don't exist an getXml...

--Edit--

I realize that the main problem is that when I select a tab in the menu
only the Toast message appears:

```
if(tabId == R.id.perfil){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Perfil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                PerfilFragment f = new PerfilFragment();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.bottomBar, f).commit();
}
```

Here is the PerfilFragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.perfil, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

Here the perfil layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:text="teste"/>
```

When I select the user icon in the menu the app should take me to the user page but only the Toast appears.

Here my activity_main

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"/>

<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs" />
```

Perfil = User.

Sorry for my english, I'm learning.

Comment: Did you have a look at [the README on the repo](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/blob/master/README.md)? In the "Adding items from XML resource" section. You add it as the `app:bb_tabXmlResource` attribute on the `<BottomBar>` element in the layout.

Comment: @Mike I didn't read right, but I added `app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs"`. Now i did this  `public boolean onCreateOptionalMenu(Layout layout){
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottomBar, layout);

        return true;
    }` is this the right way?

Comment: If the `<BottomBar>` is in your `Activity`'s layout, it seems you shouldn't have to have any other code to inflate it or its menu. That is, you shouldn't need the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` override for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I commented this line in my code and I realize with your help that the problem isn't this. That is the problem:

Comment: `if(tabId == R.id.perfil){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Perfil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    PerfilFragment f = new PerfilFragment();
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.bottomBar, f).commit();
                }else if(tabId == R.id.android){
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Android", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    AndroidFragment f = new AndroidFragment();
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.bottomBar, f).commit();
                }`

Comment: The Toast Message Show when I click in an icon, but they don't take me to the current layout

Comment: Here the unique function in PerfilFragment and AndroidFragment:`public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.android, container, false);

        return v;
    }`

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're saying, but if you have updates to your question, please [edit] it to add the details, rather than posting them in comments.

Comment: The `R.id` that you pass to the `replace()` transaction is the ID of the container that will hold the `Fragment`. If `R.id.bottomBar` is the ID for the actual `BottomBar`, then that `Fragment` is being added inside the `BottomBar`, which is probably not what you mean to do. You want that `R.id` to be whatever container `ViewGroup` - like a `<FrameLayout>`, for example - you have in your layout to hold the `Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks, Mike you solved my problem, I missed the FrameLayout ID as you can see at the end of my question. Now I added ID in <FrameLayout> and I am passing R.id.FrameLayoutID and everything is great.